# File Sync is disconnected problem with ubuntuone

Tags: ubuntu-one, 12.04

I'm looking to upload a file to my Ubuntu One cloud, but when I open the Ubuntu One Control Panel on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine, it notifies me that "File Sync is disconnected." So, naturally, I'll click the "Connect" button next to it, and it will say "File Sync in progress..." and it will want to upload my file, but it doesn't seem like anything is happening. Then, after a minute, it will simply regress into "File Sync is disconnected." This, of course, frustrates me greatly, and causes me to wonder, what could I possibly be doing wrong?

I have already tried `u1sdtool -q`, `u1sdtool --status`, and `u1sdtool --start`
the status report is :

```
> u1sdtool --status
State: WAITING
    connection: With User With Network
    description: waiting before try connecting again
    is_connected: False
    is_error: False
    is_online: False
    queues: WORKING
```

Although I am able to add or remove devices from both web service as well as UbuntuOne on my desktop running ubuntu 12.04 (beta).

Comment: It looks like it's not detecting that you are online. Are you connecting using NetworkManager?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that.